# pandas to_sql not handling nan

Tags: python, pandas, sybase, pandas-to-sql

I'm just trying to send to sybase ASE some float data containing nan, the expected result being a NULL in the database.
The pandas version is 1.3.5, and python Python 3.8.12, and sqlalchemy  1.4.28 .

Creation of the table:

```
create table test(head VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL, val FLOAT NULL, primary key(head))
```

Creation of the dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"head":["A","B","C"], "val":[1.2,np.nan,42.0]}) #math.nan gets the same result
```

And now the code that crashes :

```
df.to_sql("test",
      con = engine,
      if_exists="replace",
      index=False,
      dtype={'head': db.types.VARCHAR(20), 'val':  db.types.FLOAT},
      chunksize=1)
```

the error message:

```
[SAP][ASE ODBC Driver][Adaptive Server Enterprise]Implicit conversion from datatype 'VARCHAR' to 'FLOAT' is not allowed.  Use the CONVERT function to run this query.
```

Any idea about what's happening? Everywhere I looked, it seemed like this ought to work like a charm!

Comment: I'd expect this to work.. If you run .dtype on val what do you get back?

Comment: @rayad :  df.dtypes gives : head     object  // val     float64 // dtype: object